# What argument does my function need to echo get_results() query results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my WordPress database query:

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'qs_css';
$db_css = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT qs_the_css 
    FROM $table_name
    WHERE qs_css_id = 1 
    "
);

echo $db_css[0]->qs_the_css;  // WORKS JUST FINE
```

However, I need the query results inside my function:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'quick_qs_db_css', 100 );
function quick_qs_db_css(  ) { ?>

<style type="text/css" id="db-css">
<?php echo $db_css[0]->qs_the_css; // OUTPUTS NILL ! ?>
</style>

<?php }
```

What arguments does the `quick_qs_db_css()` function need ? Is it possible to pass query results to a function?

I would prefer not to include the query inside the `quick_qs_db_css()` function.

**Update:**

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'quick_qs_db_css', 100 );
function quick_qs_db_css( $db_css ) { ?>


<?php var_dump( $db_css[0]->qs_the_css); // ALSO RETURNS NULL ?>  


<?php }
```

Any input would be very much appreciated ! Thanking in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, inside function the $db_css have a local visibility and the variable isn't visible inside the function. So, you should pass the $db_css variable as argument.

Comment: Thank you Igor, I passed $db_css as an argument, but I still get null...

Comment: how do you call the function? You just changed the function signature. I guess you should use the
add_action( 'wp_head', 'quick_qs_db_css', 100, 1); and somehow you can pass arguments to the quick_qs_db_css functions, but I don't know how.
Please, look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action. You should call function with parameters.

Comment: You can also put your query code to separate function
function getResults() {
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'qs_css';
$db_css = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT qs_the_css 
    FROM $table_name
    WHERE qs_css_id = 1 
    "
);

return $db_css;
}
And then call the function inside quick_qs_db_css like this:
 $db_css = getResults();
Or you can put the code with get data from db to your function.

Comment: @IgorChemin ,  Thank you so much!  It works perfectly with return.   Appreciate it !

Comment: As I found in wordpress docs you can't pass your own parameters with add_action of predefined wordpress action, you should look which parameters you can pass inside appropriate do_action('wp_head'). So in this case you should put the logic of getting data from db to your function and call as different function but you can't pass you custom parameters https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#more-information